# Convert video as soon as possible to 854x480p and bitrate 1100kb/s [ffmpeg]

Tags: ffmpeg, debian

Is any fast solution to convert video file to 854x480p and bitrate 1100kb/s using ffmpeg.
because now it goes with speed of 10 kb / s.

I using this command:

```
ffmpeg -y -threads 8 -i /var/filmy/'.$new_name.' -b 1200k -minrate 1200k -maxrate 1200k -bufsize 1200k -ab 124k -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict -2 -ac 2 -ar 44100 -s 854x480 -y /var/filmy/'.implode('.',array_slice(explode('.',$result['ffilename']), 0, -1)).'.mp4
```

CPU: model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz

RAM: 32 GB

there is a solution?

Comment: Add `-preset ultrafast` right after `-vcodec libx264`.

Comment: no is around 20 kb/s ;/

Comment: What about a different codec, e.g. `-vcodec mpeg2video` or `-vcodec libxvid`, or possibly `-vcodec ffv1`?

Comment: -vcodec mpeg2video this codec is very fast but with no screen, only audio. Rest of them not work properly

Comment: `-vcodec mpeg2video` works fine on my side. Do you see any error message when you encode or attempt to watch the output file? (Certainly you should.)

Comment: [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/x2HpqKXz) my output from ffmpeg

Comment: It seems that it works. Can you show an output of `ffprobe` or `ffplay`? Btw, you should use smaller `bufsize`, e.g. `-b:v 1200k -minrate 1200k -maxrate 1200k -bufsize 800k`, and remove the `preset` option.